# Defining the connectivity of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, network

Consider a simple binary undirected graph, which adjacency matrix is $A = \{a_{i,j}\} \in \{0, 1\}^{N \times N}.$

Suppose that all vertices of such graph have at least one neighbors, i.e.

$$k_i = \sum_{j=1}^N{a_{i,j}} \geq 1.$$

How do we call this graph?

Reading the definition of [connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)), I did not find anything about this particular case.

I would say that it is "minimally connected".

Is there a proper nomenclature for these graphs?

Comment: What is a "binary" graph?

Comment: Binary stands for "non-weighted", i.e. the entries of $A$ are in the set $\{0, 1\}$, not in $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Requiring that every vertex have positive degree is not sufficient to make the graph connected. You may describe your graph as having no isolated vertices.

Comment: this makes sense. thanks a lot.